# If I got two-day review suspension sometime back, the next ban of 7 days is applying after a single mistake?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I was previously got banned for two days from reviewing for passing a link only answer as "no action needed".

After that, I had many days of carefully reviewing and only today I did [a single mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/13333073)

Immediately after that single mistake, I was banned for 7 days. Is this the normal procedure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

If you fail a single audit within 30 days since the last ban, you get banned again.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification @Floern :)

Comment: @Lahiru if you want to go risk-free, you could either wait 30 days or only review posts that are clear cases and [skip](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) if you are not 100% sure.

Comment: Great, I'll keep that in mind. Yeah, sometimes they are really tricky. Thanks :)

Comment: It seems as though we are punishing way too quickly.  Doesn't that drive people away from making reviews?

Comment: @JonH couldn't agree more :)

Comment: @JonH, it does. At least me - I don't do reviews - tried once or twice, but most of them are not really clear, so I don't do them anymore - don't really want a ban. Not that the effect is different - at the end, I just don't do any reviews anyway, but still...